# Caching bunch of simple queries in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, caching

In my app there're objects, and they belong to countries, regions, cities, types, groups, companies and other sets. Every set is rather simple - it has id, name and sometimes some pointers to other sets, and it never changes. Some sets are small and I load them in before_filter like that:

```
@countries = Country.all
@regions = Region.all
```

But then I call, for example, 
    offer.country.name 
or 
    region.country.name
and my app performs a separate db query-by-id, although I've already loaded them all. After that I perform query through :include, and this case ids, generated by eager loading, do not depend on either I've already loaded this data with another query-by-id or not.

So I want some cache. For example, I may generate hashes with keys as records-ids in my before_filter and then call @countries[offer.country_id].name. This case it seems I don't need eager loading and it's easy turn on Rails.cache here. But maybe there's some smart built-in rails solution that does not require to rewrite everything?

Answer (score 1):

Caching lists of models like that won't cache individual instances of that exist in other model's associations.

The Rails team has worked on implementing [*Identity Maps*](http://edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2011/04/21/activerecord-identity-map/index.html) in Rails 3.1 to solve this exact problem, but it is disabled by default for now. You can enable it and see if it works for your problem.

Comment: I switched to Rails 3.1 and turned on identity maps, and it seems they work,so I have only one instance of each @country = Country.find(1). But it's not exactly what I want because identity maps don't reduce number of queries to database. Ideally there must be an sql-parser that compares two queries and finds that one results (partially) match anothers. The common task is complex, but it seems rather easy to use some cache-by-id  in active record find(:ids) and all methods.